# How to store various types of function pointers together?

Tags: c++, c, function-pointers

Normal pointers can be stored using a generic `void*`. e.g.

```
void* arr[10];
arr[0] = pChar;
arr[1] = pINt;
arr[2] = pA;
```

Sometime back, I came across a discussion that, `void*` may not be capable enough to store a function pointer without data-loss in all platforms (say 64-bit and more). I am not sure about this fact though.

If that's true, then what is the most portable way to store a collection of function pointers ? 
[Note: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4699018/how-to-create-a-container-that-holds-different-types-of-function-pointers-in-c) doesn't satisfactorily answer this.]

**Edit**: I will be storing this function pointers with an index. There is a typecasting associated with every index whenever this collection is accessed. As of now, I am interested only to make an array or `vector` of it.]

Comment: How will you *call* the function? You have to recover the original type of the function pointer somehow. It's important to understand this in order to answer your question.

Comment: Do the function pointers have *anything* in common? What are you going to do with them once they are in the collection?

Comment: @ybungalobill, I have edited my question. As of now, I want a plain array. Don't want to resort on `template` solution.

Comment: Can you show a use case of "There is a typecasting associated with every index whenever this collection is accessed."?

Comment: void * not capable to store function pointers? Someone can confirm this? I believe from the cpu  point of view, it does not exist anything like "pointers to", but just "pointers".

Comment: @iammilind: if I understand you correctly, then you know that index 0 is type X, index 1 is type Y, etc... Then why don't you use a struct of function pointers of those known types (X f0; Y f1; ...)? If you can't do this, that means that you *do have* something in common (the uniform operation that you do on each item of this collection). So please, help us understand you design choices. Note that your example with `void*` doesn't make sense in real code either.

Comment: @Shin: Conflict of standards. Both C++ and C say that function pointers should not be cast to void* (undefined behavior). POSIX says that they must be able to be cast to void* (presumably Windows says the same; it uses DLLs). The reason C and C++ say no: There are plenty of weird architecture machines where function pointers are very, very different from data pointers. The reason POSIX says yes: POSIX doesn't give a hoot about Harvard architecture machines.

Comment: @Hammen thanks you interesting; to me this actually means that they exist CPUs that have different address space for data and code and that data pointer registers are smaller than code pointer registers; or there are other possibilities that I am missing? An example of such a CPU?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can convert a function pointer to another function pointer of any function type and back without loss.

So as long as when you make the call through the function pointer you typecast it back to the correct type first, you can store all of your function pointers in something like:

```
typedef void (*fcn_ptr)(void);  // 'generic' function pointer

fcn_ptr arr[10];
```

Comment: +1 for only correct answer. You should probably cite the standard(s) since the rest of SO seems to think OP's perfectly reasonable request is misguided, illegal, or impossible to use correctly.

Answer (score 6):

A pointer to a function can be converted to a pointer to a function of a different type with a `reinterpret_cast`. If you convert it back to the original type you are guaranteed to get the original value back so you can then use it to call the function. (ISO/IEC 14882:2003 5.2.10 [expr.reinterpret.cast] / 6)

You now only need to select an arbitrary function pointer type for your array. `void(*)()` is a common choice.

E.g.

```
int main()
{
    int a( int, double );
    void b( const char * );

    void (*array[])() = { reinterpret_cast<void(*)()>(a)
                        , reinterpret_cast<void(*)()>(b) };

    int test = reinterpret_cast< int(*)( int, double) >( array[0] )( 5, 0.5 );
    reinterpret_cast< void(*)( const char* ) >( array[1] )( "Hello, world!" );
}
```

Naturally, you've lost a lot of type safety and you will have *undefined behavior* if you call a function through a pointer to a function of a different type.

Comment: This is no improvement over a union solution. Worse, even, because the union can be in a class which controls and remembers which function pointer type it's holding. Also, `reinterpret_cast` ***can't*** bring back your exact original data if you stored it in some narrower variable in the interim.

Comment: @spraff: I am talking explicitly about the special case of casting from a pointer to function type to another pointer to function type and then back to the original type. You are _guaranteed_ to get the original value back. Look up my reference.

Comment: @spraff: Personally, I don't see the advantage of using a union of function pointers. It's just as dangerous to read the wrong union member as it is to reinterpret_cast a function pointer to the wrong type but with a union you also have to update the union every time you add a new function type to the list of possible types that you want to store in it which is a maintenance overhead with no additional benefit.

Comment: Personally, I like Charles approach better. One, it's honest. That `reinterpret_cast` is a clue that something underhanded is going on. Two, it's very extensible. Three, I just don't like unions. They harken way back to Fortran EQUIVALENCE days.

Answer (score 3):

Use a union of your function pointer types, this works in both C and C++ and assures sufficient storage for the pointers (which are likely the same size, still...)

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things that make up a function pointer's type.

- the memory address of the code
- the argument signature
- the linkage/name mangling
- the calling convention
- for member functions, [some other stuff too](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/FastDelegate.aspx)

If these features aren't uniform across your function pointers then you can't sensibly store them in the same container.

You can, however [bind different aspects](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html#std-function) into a `std::function` which is a callable object that only requires the argument signature and return type to be uniform.

It may be a good time to re-think the problem in terms of virtual functions. Does this mishmash of function pointers have a coherent interface that you can express? If not, then you're doomed anyway :-)

RE: Hasturkun, you can store heterogeneous function pointers in unions, yes, they're just POD, but you will also need to store information about what type of pointer it is so that you can choose the correct member to call. Two problems with this:

- there is a per-item overhead,
- you have to manually check that you're using the right one consistently all the time, this is a burden with nonlocal effects -- it's a spreading poison.

Far better to have one container per type, it will clarify the code and make it safer. Or, use a proxy such as `std::function` to make them all have the same type.