# Is this a generic function pointer and is it dangerous?

Tags: c, pointers

Learning and messing up with function pointers, I noticed a way to initialize void function pointers and cast them. Yet, although I don‘t receive any warning or error, either with GCC or VS’s compiler, I wanted to know whether it was dangerous or a bad practice to do this as I don't see this way of initializing function pointers often on the Internet. Moreover, do we call this generic function pointer?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <conio.h>

#define PAUSE (_getch())

uint16_t add(const uint16_t x, const uint16_t y) {
    return x + y;
}

char chr(uint8_t test) {
    return (char)test;
}

int main(void) {

    void(*test)() = (void*)add;

    const uint16_t x = 1, y = 1;
    uint16_t value = ((uint16_t(*)())test)(x, y);

    test = (void*)chr;

    printf("%d\n", add(x, y));                    // 2
    printf("%d\n", value);                        // 2
    printf("%c\n", ((char(*)())test)(100));       // d

    PAUSE;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "as I don't see this way of initializing function pointers often on the internet" - which internet are you looking at?

Comment: Related: In C, `void (*fn)()` and `void (*fn)(void)` have different meanings. (which you're taking advantage of in your code, btw).

Comment: void (*fn)(void) declaes explicitly a pointer to a function which doesn't expect any argument whereas void (*fn)() can?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6640254/how-to-store-various-types-of-function-pointers-together

Comment: You're going to corrupt the call stack with this if the parameters are passed on stack.

Comment: @AlexeiAverchenko Still in C99 and still in C11. You may be thinking of C++.

Comment: @D.Naesuko Yes, `void (*fn)()` points to a function that can receive *any* arguments, of which the number and type is deduced from the very first call. It's evil and error-prone and in 99.5% of the cases, it leads to undefined behavior.

Comment: There isn't really a generic function pointer.  Standard C does not guarantee that the size of a function pointer is the same as the size of an object pointer (in fact, there are a number of non-guarantees about pointer sizes).  POSIX makes up for it, for Unix-like systems, by mandating that object pointers and function pointers should be the same size.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C cast void pointer to function pointer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13696918/c-cast-void-pointer-to-function-pointer)

Comment: @PascalCuoq you're right.

Comment: Is the fact that you did not get warnings due to the fact that the code does not have problems or the fact that you did not turn on warnings in your compiler settings? Perhaps you should try the latter. With GCC, use `-Wmost -std=c99` and, for good measure, `-pedantic`. You will get several warnings.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is this a generic function pointer

No, if I'm not terribly mistaken, there's no such thing as a "generic function pointer" in C.

> and is it dangerous?

Yes, it is. It is evil.

---

There are a couple of things you need to know. First, unless you are running a system that conforms to POSIX,

```
void(*test)() = (void*)add;
```

is **wrong.** `void *` is a pointer-to-***object*** type, and as such, it is not compatible with function pointers. (At least not in standard C -- as I mentioned, POSIX requires it to be compatible with function pointers too.)

The second thing is that `void (*fp)()` and `void (*fp)(void)` are different. The former declaration permits `fp` to take any number of parameters of any type, and the number of arguments and their types will be inferred when the compiler sees the first call to the function (pointer).

Another important aspect is that function pointers are guaranteed to be convertible across each other (AFAIK this manifests in them having the same representation and alignment requirements). This means that any function pointer can be assigned to (the address of) any function (after an appropriate cast), so long as you do not **call** a function through a pointer to an incompatible type. The behavior is well-defined if and only if you cast the pointer back to the original type before calling it.

So, if you want a "generic" function pointer, you can just write something like

```
typedef void (*fn_ptr)(void);
```

and then you could assign any pointer to function to an object of type `fn_ptr`. What you have to pay attention to is, again, the conversion to the right type when invoking the function, as in:

```
int add(int a, int b);

fn_ptr fp = (fn_ptr)add; // legal
fp(); // WRONG!
int x = ((int (*)(int, int))fp)(1, 2); // good
```

Answer (score 5):

There are two serious problems here:

1. A cast from a function pointer to an object pointer (such as `void *`) triggers undefined behavior: in principle, it could crash your system (though in practice there are many systems where it will work fine). Instead of `void *`, it's better to use a function-pointer type for this purpose.
2. You're tricking the compiler into unknowingly passing an `int` to a function expecting a `uint8_t`. That's also undefined behavior, and it's very dangerous. Since the compiler doesn't know that it's doing this, it can't even take the most basic necessary steps to avoid smashing the stack — you're really gambling here. Similarly, this is a bit more subtle, but you're *also* tricking the compiler into passing two `int`-s into a function expecting two `uint16_t`-s.

And two lesser problems:

1. The notation for function pointer types on their own — e.g., in a cast — is confusing. I think it's better to use a typedef: `typedef void (*any_func_ptr)(); any_func_ptr foo = (any_func_ptr)(bar)`.
2. It's undefined behavior to call a function pointer with a different signature than the actual function has. You can avoid that with careful coding — more careful than your current code — but it's tricky and risky.

Answer (score 2):

You may corrupt the call stack with this, depending on the calling convention, specifically who's doing the cleanup: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions With the callee cleanup, the compiler has no way of knowing how many variables you have passed on the stack at the point of cleanup, so passing the wrong number of parameters or parameters of the wrong size will end corrupting the call stack.

On x64, everyone uses the caller cleanup, so you're safe in this regard. The parameter values, however, will in general be a mess. In your example, on x64, they will be whatever was in the corresponding registers at the time.

Answer (score 2):

C11 §6.3.2.3 (8) says:

> A pointer to a function of one type may be converted to a pointer to a function of another type and back again; the result shall compare equal to the original pointer. If a converted pointer is used to call a function whose type is not compatible with the referenced type, the behavior is undefined.

And §6.7.6.3 (15) says about compatible types of functions:

> […] If one type has a parameter type list and the other type is specified by a function declarator that is not part of a function definition and that contains an empty identifier list, the parameter list shall not have an ellipsis terminator and the type of each parameter shall be compatible with the type that results from the application of the default argument promotions. […]

So, if you had `add` and `chr` to take `int` arguments (an int has at least a width of 16 bit) that would be OK (if you didn't cast the function pointer to `void *`), but, as it is, it is UB.