# Is this allowed to call functions with different prototypes by a pseudo-generic function pointer?

Tags: c, function-pointers

Assuming that all functions share the same return type, is it valid to call each one by a "generic" function pointer, that is declared with empty parentheses (so it does not specify its arguments)?

Here is an example code, that illustrates it:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void fun1(void)
{
    printf("fun1\n");   
}

void fun2(int a)
{
    printf("fun2: %d\n", a);
}

void fun3(int a, int b)
{
     printf("fun3: %d %d\n", a, b);
}

int main(void)
{
    void (*pf)(); // pseudo-generic function pointer

    pf = fun1;
    pf();

    pf = fun2;
    pf(0);

    pf = fun3;
    pf(1, 2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Function pointer without arguments types?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20835534/function-pointer-without-arguments-types)

Comment: Interesting question. Valid as in "does it compile and run as expected?" yes, Does say "compiling with `-Wall` work without warnings?" on my compilers yes :-)

Comment: Yes, no warning even in paranoid mode `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wconversion` by GCC 4.9... @Dilettant

Comment: as per K&R it's legal.

Comment: @JohnColeman: I'd say is very close, but OP's question was more about validity of declaration, than function calling.

Comment: I'm not going to spend the time to look it up in the C standard, but empty argument lists are an old K&R feature. In K&R C there was no problem with what you're doing modulo auto-arg promotion. I.e. pointed-to functions can only use arguments of promoted-to types (e.g. float to double). Since the standard tends to honor K&R conventions wherever reasonable, I'd be shocked if this is regarded as incorrect.

Comment: @JohnColeman: At first I also thought eg. already anwsered at ["Is this a generic function pointer and is it dangerous?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20809790/is-this-a-generic-function-pointer-and-is-it-dangerous) but I think it is a different and interesting (IMO) question also not really matching ["Function pointer without arguments types?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20835534/function-pointer-without-arguments-types).

Comment: @GrzegorzSzpetkowski I guess that question was more about the legality of the declaration rather than its semantics. I'll retract the close vote.

Comment: Parameters/arguments are optional; that is, a function may contain no parameters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may do similar stuff, but not exactly that way. When you call a function through a function pointer you have to be sure that the prototype on the calling side is exactly as the function was defined.

Now a function declarations with empty parenthesis isn't even a prototype, so this is not the right way to call it. The main reason is that the calling convention might be slightly different than you'd expect. For `()` functions special rules apply, namely narrow types are converted to `int`, `unsigned` or `double`.

Now what you may do is *store* a function pointer in `pf` as you do, but then you'd always have to convert it back to the correct function pointer before the call, such as

```
((void (*)(int, int))pf)(a, b);
```

This is barely readable and much errorprone. You should avoid such gymnastics as much as you can.